# ObjectAlreadyExistsException при попытке запустить джобы по расписанию использую spring-quartz?

Tags: java, spring, quartz

Приложение spring, развернутое на websphere 8.5.5.13
Сервер представляет собой кластер из нескольких нод, например двух

У меня есть задача, которая должна выполняться по расписанию единожды. Только раз например в 50 секунд

Изначально использовал @Scheduler для вызова сервисов, но стало понятно, что задача выполняется сразу на нескольких нодах одновременно. В качестве решения проблемы выбрал spring-quartz

Job

```
@DisallowConcurrentExecution
public class QuartzJob implements Job{
    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass());

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext) throws JobExecutionException {
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "========HELLO========%n");
    }
}
```

Config

```
@Configuration
@Import(PersistenceConfig.class)
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:application.properties", "classpath:quartz.properties"})
public class QuartzConfig {
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;
    @Autowired
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
    private Random random = new Random();

    @Bean
    @DependsOn(value = {"entityManagerFactory", "dataSource"})
    public JobDetail cronJob() {
        return JobBuilder.newJob(QuartzJob.class).requestRecovery(true).withIdentity("helloJob"+random.nextInt(99999)).build();
    }

@Bean
@DependsOn(value = {"entityManagerFactory", "dataSource"})
public Trigger cronTrigger() {
    return TriggerBuilder
            .newTrigger()
            .withIdentity("helloTrigger")
            .withSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule().repeatForever().withIntervalInSeconds(50))
            .build();
}

@Bean
@DependsOn(value = {"entityManagerFactory", "dataSource"})
public Scheduler cronScheduler(JobDetail cronJob, Trigger cronTrigger) throws SchedulerException {
    Scheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();
    scheduler.scheduleJob(cronJob, cronTrigger);
    scheduler.start();
    return scheduler;
}
```

}

То есть обычная связка job->trigger->scheduler,

Так же были созданы таблицы для работы quartz в кластере и его настройки
[таблицы](https://github.com/quartz-scheduler/quartz/blob/quartz-2.3.x/quartz-core/src/main/resources/org/quartz/impl/jdbcjobstore/tables_oracle.sql) и проперти-файл:

```
#============================================================================
# Configure Main Scheduler Properties  
#============================================================================

org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = ClusteredScheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = AUTO
#============================================================================
# Configure ThreadPool  
#============================================================================

org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 4
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority = 5
#============================================================================
# Configure JobStore  
#============================================================================

org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold = 60000

org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.oracle.OracleDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties = false
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = DATAMY
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = QRTZ_
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = true
org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval = 20000
org.quartz.dataSource.DATAMY.jndiURL = java:comp/env/jdbc/DATAMY
```

Теперь джоба запускается на одной из нод, а на второй сыпятся сообщения об ошибках, что при попытке сохранить запущенную джобу, такая джоба уже нашлась в базе

> Caused by: org.quartz.ObjectAlreadyExistsException: Unable to store
>   Job : 'DEFAULT.helloJob', because one already exists with this
>   identification.

Подскажите как донастроить Quartz чтобы задачи запускались только на одной из нод по расписанию?

В базе в райтайме в таблице QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS только одна запись при этом
helloJob89041 DEFAULT quartz.QuartzJob

Я подозреваю, что причина может быть в том, что я не удаляю джобу после того, как она была записана в базу. То есть после ее выполнения, на scheduler как-то должен быть вызван deleteJob, но как это сделать пока не понятно. Сама по себе джоба не удаляется.